# How do I open a file that leads into the Terminal?

Tags: command-line

Let's say put a file on the desktop, and when it opens, it opens in the terminal. If I want to do this, what extension can I use in "Save As" of the Text Editor? (e.g. open.shell)
Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Some of the extension you can use in Save As when using a text editor, you can use .bat, .sh, .txt.

You can also use [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) it opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application.

You can also right click on the file from Nautulis, and choose open in terminal, and if its openable in terminal it will open.  To have that added to Nautilus, just look at 
[Add Open in Terminal Command to Nautilus Context Menu](http://www.distrogeeks.com/open-terminal-here-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

The **terminal is not for open files with it**! You can edit/open/view files **from inside of the terminal** using commands like `nano file_name`/`xdg-open file_name`/`cat file_name`.

Also (maybe about this thing you are interested) you can run directly in terminal some executable text files (like bash script files). To do this, open Nautilus, go to **Files** → **Preferences**, select **Behaviour** tab and select the option you prefer for executable text files:

[image: file preferences]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the script in your favorite editor for example gedit
2. At script's first line put a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)
3. Save the script somewhere using the .sh extension for example ~/Desktop/myscript.sh
4. Open Nautilus preferences, at Executable Text Files check the first option *Run executable text files when they are opened*
5. Double click to open the script.

As a reference example you can use the following simple bash script which prints a line on terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am running this executable file"
read -p "Press enter to exit"
```

When you run the script, a terminal window will open executing the `echo` and `read` commands

*About shebang:*
The first line in the script `#!/bin/bash` "tells" the system which [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) to use in order to precess the command written in it.